# Missing locales on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, centos7, localization, glibc

We are running a Werewolf cluster and the node images are missing the locales. Only C and POSIX are available. The system uses CentOS 7 as base.

It isn't really an issue but it's a very annoying to receive warnings at each command, like those:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
```

I've double checked if `glibc` is installed and everything appears to be ok:

```
[root@n01 ~]# rpm -qa | grep -i glibc
glibc-common-2.17-106.el7_2.6.x86_64
glibc-headers-2.17-106.el7_2.6.x86_64
glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.6.x86_64
glibc-devel-2.17-106.el7_2.6.x86_64
```

And `locale -a` outputs this:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
POSIX
```

Any idea to generate all the missing locales?

Comment: try an strace to see what file is missing: strace -f locale -a 2>&1|grep open

Answer (score 2):

A tad late, but yum has glibc-langpack-* modules:

```
yum list glibc-langpack-\*
```

Comment: Centos8 has it. Centos7 doesn't :(

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
yum reinstall glibc-common
```

which should just erm, reinstall the package.

Comment: Already tried this. Unfortunately it does not work. :(

Comment: It would have been a good thing to mention that then.

Comment: @ViníciusFerrão did you solve this? Same problem for me on a brand new AWS EC2 instance. I'm missing the language packs and cannot figure out how to generate them.

Comment: Update: I fixed this, probably not in the best way, but it works, and could not find any solution to reinstalling/replacing the missing files another way. My `/usr/share/i18n/locales` and `/usr/share/i18n/charmaps` folders were completely empty. No amount of reinstalling packages seemed to fix this. I finally took the contents of the folder from another instance that was working fine, then ran `sudo localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8` to generate the locale information for me. `locale -a` now shows en_US as available and all my errors are gone.

Answer (score 0):

since I don't find any better answer, you fix this by setting LANG , LANGUAGE and LC_ALL on logon, for example on /etc/profile add :

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```